# Using import within a style attribute

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

First let me be perfectly clear. I am talking about importing a css file within a html `style=''` attribute.    You can assume Internet Explorer 9.

**I DON'T CARE ABOUT `<link>` TAGS or other methods of importing css.**

Lets say I have a simple .css file:

```
#inputArea{
width: width:72px;
}
```

Why is this import not working?

```
<input type=text id='inputArea' style="@import url(simple.css);">
```

When this import does work?

```
<style>
    @import url(simple.css);
</style>
```

When does a `style=""` attribute import work?  Why isn't this one working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `style` attribute takes a list of [declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets), and applies properties from that list specifically to the owner element.

`@import` is not a declaration and does not apply to a particular element. It can only appear in the top level of a style sheet along with the selectors and other `@`-constructs that comprise the [statements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#statements).

It doesn't make any sense to import a stylesheet, that contains rules selecting other elements, into an element's inline style. It's like saying:

```
<input type=text id='inputArea' style="body { margin: 0 }">
```

which is just as meaningless.

Comment: what if you need to import some font?